# How to get $Y^2=Y$ but $YY^{-1}=I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How to define an algebraic structure $A$ in which there are two objects -- either elements or subsets, denoted by $Y$ and $I$ respectively, satisfying the condition $Y^2=Y$ but $YY^{-1}=I$?

Further explanation: Suppose $A$ is a group and $Y$ is a subgroup, while $I=\{1\}$. Then $Y^2=YY=Y$ holds. But $YY^{-1}=YY=Y\neq I$. This is not what I want.

Comment: And what is $Y^{-1}$? By using it you mean that in your structure there exists already some kind of identity element?

Comment: You can define it by your self. At present, I define $Y^{-1}=\{y^{-1}:y\in Y\}$. But I have not found what I want.

Comment: I don't get the question. If I am free to define $I$ and $Y$ why not choose $I=Y$ in your example above and be done?

Comment: If I may define it, let $Y^{-1}$ be equal to $I$. Then we have the group with two elements. $Y$ is identity and $I$ is the second element. :)

Comment: @sas: But then $Y^2 \ne Y$ if $Y$ and $I$ are the elements of the group with two elements.

Comment: from $Y^2=Y$ by multiplying by $Y^{-1}$ you alwasy get $Y=1$, where $1$ is the identity of your structure

Comment: If multiplication of subsets is defined as $XY = \{ xy : x \in X, y \in Y \}$, then in most cases $YY^{-1} \neq I$: Let $y \in Y$ and let $x \in Y^{-1}$ be the inverse of an element in $Y$ different from $y$. Then $yx \neq 1$ but $yx \in YY^{-1}$.

Comment: @mike4ty4 nobody told that $I$ should be identity. Let $Y$ be identity. :) It is gibberish, by the way, I do not get the question, really.

Comment: @sas: But then we have $Y = I$ (follows from $Y^{-1} = Y$, so $I = YY^{-1} = YY = Y^2 = Y$), and so only *one* object. :)

Comment: @mike4ty4 not necessary — $Y$ is identity, $I=Y^{-1}$ and there is no connection between $Y$ and $Y^{-1}$ — just bad luck, that symbols look similar.

Comment: @sas: So $Y^{-1}$ is not inverse?

Comment: @sas: That would do it, I suppose. But whenever I see "$Y^{-1}$", I think of some sort of "inverse".

Comment: @mike4ty4, surely. Very convenient, isn't it?

Comment: I have not given the definitions on the operation $Y^2$ and $Y^{-1}$. I left these for free discussion. Of course, $Y=I$ is not the solution I want. I hope $Y$ and $I$ should be two distinct objects, either elements or subsets.

Comment: You do realize that if your operation is associative and has $I$ as a neutral element, then
$$Y=YI=Y(YY^{-1})=(Y^2)Y^{-1}=YY^{-1}=I.$$ So something has to give. Are you ok with dropping associativity? Also, isn't $Y^{-1}$ necessarily a third object distinct from both $Y$ and $I$?

Answer (score 6):

Take $Y=(0,\infty)$ and define $AB=A+B=\{a+b:a\in A, b\in B\}$ and $Y^{-1}=-Y$. Then $Y^2=Y$ and $YY^{-1}=\mathbb R$. Now set $I=\mathbb R$.

Comment: or $Y=(1,\infty)$ and $AB=\{ab: a\in A,b\in B\}$. Then $Y^2=Y$ and $YY^{-1}=(0,\infty)$

Comment: This is a smart constructions. But why $YY^{-1}=\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes, to some extent, my question is gibberish. You can define what means $Y^2$ and $Y^{-1}$. Anyway, I want two DISTINCT objects, $Y$ and $I$, such that $Y^2=Y$ but $Y^{-1}=I$.

Comment: $Y^{-1}=-Y$ so $YY^{-1}$ is the set of numbers that one can obtain by $a+b$ where $a>0$ and $b<0$, which is the whole $\mathbb R$. May be the "exponential" version that I gave in the comment is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I realize a very simple answer for my question. If we define $f(x)=x^2 \bmod n$, where $n=p\cdot q$ with two distinct primes $p$ and $q$. Then, there exist many fixed pointx, i.e., $f(x)=x$. In this case, it is apparently for any fixed point $x$, $x^2=x$ but $x\cdot x^{-1}=1$.

For example, if $n=3\cdot 7=21$. There are a lot of fixed points that are depicted in the following figure.

[image]